# tx_news starttime and endtime doesn't work who they should

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, tx-news

I use the tx_news 2.3.0 to publish article. We did some changes on the page (but the tx_news was not updated) and since then starttime and endtime of news-article acts strange:

It seems like everything works fine with a delay of ~18days. So if I set starttime to NOW the article will be published in 18days. If I set it to NOW-18DAYs it will get published today. The same with the endtime. If I set endtime to NOW-19DAYs the article is published. If I set it to NOW-17DAYs the article is not anymore published.

I checked the date on the server. Also normal content get published correctly when I use starttime and endtime. Also in the backend the article have the small clock on it and there it is right (without the strange delay).  What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not found out what the problem is and it is very illogical I created a work around with a cronjob that handles the starttime and publish the article if current date > starttime.